# Determine which port my exchange service is using for e-mail sending -> cakePhP CakeEmail

Tags: email, cakephp, smtp, outlook-2007

I am trying to send mails with cakephp using the smtp protocol.

This is my email.php:

```
class EmailConfig {

    public $smtp = array(
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'from' => array('account@mail.sk' => 'Me'),
        'host' => 'ip_address',
        'port' => 1234,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'account',
        'password' => 'password',

/* dont know what these parameters below are for */
        'client' => null, 
        'log' => true,
        //'charset' => 'utf-8',
        //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    );
```

This is a function that I use for testing (after clicking on link it should send some dummy mail):

```
    public function testSendEmail() {
        $this->autoRender = false;
                    $email = new CakeEmail('smtp');
        $email->from(array('account@mail.com' => 'Test'));
        $email->to('me@gmail.com');
        $email->subject('Test subject');
        $email->send('Dummy post');
    }
```

I think my code is OK (alltough I did not try it out, since gmail is restricted in our office, so I could not try it with my gmail settings). After clicking on the link ($this->Html->link('link', array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'send_mail'));) nothing happens (site refreshes) I do not get any errors whatsoever, not even in the tmp/error.log

I guess my port is not correct. (but any other reason, that would occur to you, will be appreciated)

**After some digging I found the host to where I need to send this, my question is this:**

How do I find the port my mailing service (Outlook 2007) is using to send messages?

**What I tried:**

1. http://www.authsmtp.com/outlook-2007/alternate-port.html , but all dialogs since image 2 vary from the pictures.
2. Also tried netstat -a in command line, but none of the two ports corresponding with my OUTLOOK worked.

**Additional notes:**

1. I code this app on localhost (xampp -> apache)
2. I added this  "extension=php_openssl.dll" line to php.ini (it was proposed in some tutorial) and no change happened (still no error, still no mail)

**UPDATE:**

Changed the name of the function to "test_send_email" and now it does not refresh but after deleteng the auto render and adding a test_send_email.ctp view to my MVC this error is displayed:

*SMTP timeout.
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.*

So I guess I am right and I do not have the correct port..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default port is 25, which was the case here.

You can check it with the cmd command telnet name_of_server 25

In outlook 2007 the server address can be found by right-clicking the message -> options -> down in the dialog box are the headers of this msg.