# Sending an email in Python: Unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python, email, outlook, smtp

I am new to Python programming and have a project to try to send a simple email to myself for testing purposes and keep encountering some errors. At first I tried using the first template from [email: Examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html) on the Python website to send a simple message. I created a plain text file with some words in it to read from.

This is my code:

```
# Import smtplib for the actual sending function
import smtplib

# Import the email modules we'll need
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# Open a plain text file for reading.  For this example, assume that
# the text file contains only ASCII characters.
fp = open('test.txt', 'r')
# Create a text/plain message
msg = MIMEText(fp.read())
fp.close()

# me == the sender's email address
# you == the recipient's email address
me = "myname@email.com"
you = "myname@email.com"
msg['Subject'] = 'The contents of %s' % 'test.txt'
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

# Send the message via our own SMTP server, but don't include the
# envelope header.
s = smtplib.SMTP('my Outlook account server')
s.sendmail(me, [you], msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

And I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last) -  on line 18:
msg['Subject'] = 'The contents of %s' % 'test.txt'
```

So I tried a different format of code that I got from [pythonRocks_1:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273198/outlook-2010-and-python-email-smtplib-info-in-proper-fields)

```
import smtplib

SERVER = 'mail.company.com'
FROM = 'jdoe@company.com'
TO = ['receiver1@company.com']
SUBJECT = "Test Subject SMTP"
TEXT = "If this is in the body of the email, test is a success!"

message = """From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\nSubject: %s\r\n
%s
""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)



try:
    s = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
    s.sendmail(FROM, TO, message) # this line is not correctly putting info in proper fields for Outlook 2010
    s.quit()
    print "Successfully sent email."

except:

    import sys, traceback

    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    print "An error occurred on line " + str(tb.tb_lineno)
    print "Error: unable to send email"
```

With this error:

```
An error occurred on line 19
Error: unable to send email
```

My line 19 reads:

```
 s = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
```

Do you think my SMTP server is incorrect? I went into my Account Settings under my Outlook 2010 email and found the SMTP server from there. I'm not exactly sure what else it could be.

Comment: are you using `msg['Subject'] = 'The contents of %s' % 'test.txt'`?

Answer (score 0):

One of the first things that jumped out to me is that you do not have a password, unless you have a very strange mail server(or are running one locally end even then... you're going to need to set that up somewhere. You are also not giving a port for the email server which, in my experience, is required.

Here is a modified version of your code that works for gmail. You'll have to, of course, make some changes to reflect your environment. This version stores your password in plain text in the source, that is a pretty bad idea and you will want to change that. A previous, similar question(here: [Determine which port my exchange service is using for e-mail sending -> cakePhP CakeEmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122508/determine-which-port-my-exchange-service-is-using-for-e-mail-sending-cakephp)) has some information about the settings/ports/etc for an exchange server.

```
import smtplib

TO = '<user>@gmail.com'
FROM = '<target>@gmail.com'
PWD = '<password>'
SERVER = "smtp.gmail.com" # gmail settings, this will come from your mail server
PORT = 587 #gmail settings, this will come from your server
SUBJECT = "Test Email"
TEXT = "This is  a test"
message = """To: {TO}\r\nFrom: {FROM}\r\nSubject:{SUBJECT}\r\n{TEXT}""".format(TO=TO, FROM=FROM, SUBJECT=SUBJECT, TEXT=TEXT)

try:
    # connect to the server and log in
    smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER, PORT)
    smtpserver.ehlo()
    smtpserver.starttls()
    smtpserver.ehlo
    smtpserver.login(FROM, PWD)

    # print our message just to ensure we have everything
    print message

    # send the message
    smtpserver.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)

    # close the server
    smtpserver.close()

    # let ues know it is done
    print 'done!'

except:
    import sys, traceback

    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    print "An error occurred on line " + str(tb.tb_lineno)
    print "Error: unable to send email"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I still can't get it to compile correctly but I think it's because I have an incorrect port number.

Comment: Something that helped me immensely when working with this sort of stuff was to try it with a google or other free, online email address first. Exchange and similar corporate email servers can be tricky and, at times, require some heft finagling. Set everything up the way you want with a test or dummy account on some free, easy to use service and, once everything is working, figure out how to refactor everything for the corporate server. I recall that my first email app had to work with a server that required SSL which was a pain(you should check this on your server as well.)